# Javascript If Else always picks option 1

Tags: javascript

So my Javascript code is supposed to randomly pick, but it always picks the first option, even if I switch the options, it always goes to the one on top. Did I make an error, or how can I get this to work?

```
function test() {
     var values = ["1","2"],
        valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
    // do something with the selected value
    alert(valueToUse);
} 

if (values = 1) {
window.location = "tail.html"; }
else if (values = 2) { window.location = "head.html"; }
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> if (values = 1) {
> ```

That's an *assignment*, not a comparison (`===`). It will always be true.

---

Additionally, you never call `test()`.

---

Additionally, you should be testing `valueToUse` not `values`, since that is where you assign your random choice.

---

Additionally, both `valueToUse` and `values` are locally scoped to the `test()` function and are not available outside it. Your assignment creates a new, global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `==` (or [`===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)) instead of `=`.

```
if (values == 1) {
  // and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the start `if (values = 1)` is not the valid way to compare.
 = annotates assignment so basically you are setting the value to 1. If you want to compare values in js, you do it this way `if (values === 1)`.

In other programming language u usually use == instead however in js if you compare it this way it will only check the value not the type of the variable  so a number 2 will match a string "2"
 `if (2 == "2") {//result is true}`.

If you use === it will check both the value and the type 
`if (2 == "2") {//result is false}`

Answer (score 1):

To make your code fly, you could return a random selected value from the array, store it in `value` and check it for the new direction. I omit `window.location` and us simply `console.log` for displaying the result of the comparison.

The comparison is strict, with a check for a string.

```js
function test() {
    var values = ["1", "2"],
        valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];

    return valueToUse;
}

var value = test();

if (value === '1') {
    console.log( "tail.html");
} else if (value === '2') {
    console.log( "head.html");
}
```